# Prove that the sum is also linear application

Tags: linear-algebra

Be two linear applications $f, g : \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$
. Show that the sum 
$f + g : \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, defined as:

$$(f + g)(v) = f(v) + g(v), \forall v \in \mathbb R^m,$$

It is also a linear application.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let check that the [linearity properties](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html) hold

- $(f + g)(v_1+v_2)=(f + g)(v_1)+(f + g)(v_2)$
- $(f + g)(cv)=c(f + g)(v)$